# Iterating over list for given function using 'for' loop

Tags: python-3.x, function, for-loop

Is it possible to iterate given function by updating the result automatically ?

Assuming that we have following function and for loop:

```
def something(m, p, f):
    alpha = (p+f)*m 
    return alpha

mlist= [100, 1000]
for m in mlist:
    alpha = something(m, 20, 1)
```

when I run it always takes last value in the list and calculating alpha. What I want to do is,  calculating alpha for each m  values in mlist.

I can manually update alpha :

```
for m in mlist: 
    m = mlist[0]
    alpha1= something(m, 20, 1)
    m = mlist[1]
    alpha2= something(m, 20, 1)
```

Is there any other way to update alpha automatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is, you are overwriting `alpha` during each iteration and at the end you are left with the value calculated using the last `m`. If you wish to retain or use all values of `alpha` you must either store them somewhere else, like another list, e.g., or use it for some calculation within the loop.

```
mlist= [100, 1000]
alphas = []
for m in mlist:
    alpha = something(m, 20, 1)
    #alphas.append(alpha) - option 1
    #do something with alpha here - option 2
```

Comment: I'm quite appreciate for your quick and explanatory answer. I just saw the missing point.